# Lack of package shadowsocks-qt5

Tags: raspberrypi

I found things very strange in my house's computers. I installed Raspberry Pi OS then apt install shadowsocks-qt5. But the port is fixed on 0 and other digital all can not work.

I try install shadowsocks-qt5 on my ThinkPad X61 with Ubuntu. Just can not find the package.

Are those a set of tricks?

Comment: You've provided no release details; but I'd look for package details on your *unstated* release of raspberry pi, then search for equivalent (`apt-cache search` for example) on your *unstated* Ubuntu system... If the two releases are far apart (year of release; and with raspberry pi it's the debian release it's based on that matters), then you'll have to adjust for that (but as you gave no release details for either, this maybe an issue, may not be...)

Answer (score 2):

According to https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-qt5/releases/tag/v3.0.0, the upstream dropped deb package support and moved to AppImage distribution instead.

Comment: Thanks. What a pity.